# Adding contacts to SugarCRM via REST. How to set email?

Tags: api, rest, sugarcrm

I managed to add a contact to SugarCRM using its set_entry REST API method. How do I add the contact's email ?  As it seems that this is field from another related module (email). So how can i set that using SET entry method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah well I added an email, email1 and email2 parameters in the name_value_parameters of set_entry on the Contact module and it worked too, with one single call.